# is it possible to send email from c++ application using winsock?

Tags: c++, winsock

is it possible to send email from c++ application using winsock? If yes how or give me pointers about what should i know/learn.

Answer (score 0):

Sure ... here is a starting point....

http://www.news2news.com/vfp/?example=385&ver=vcpp

I am assuming you are using simple C++ ...